# How to split the content placeholder line by line into a text shape powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2010

I am new to vb and power point , trying to run a macro in **power point 2010**. What i am trying to achieve is, when the macros is run, it should **split the contents in the content placeholder area line by line, and placing each line in a new text box shape.**

I had done some work, but not able to move forward. The macro function is below

```
Sub HelloWorldMacro()

Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape
' Current slide
Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)

For Each s In Sld.Shapes
    ' Condition - not to grab contents from title area.
    If s.Name <> "Title 1" Then
        If s.HasTextFrame Then
            With s.TextFrame
                If .HasText Then MsgBox .TextRange.Text
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

With this i been able to grab the text from content area into a msg box. But not able to split it and place it in a text shape area.

Also done tried some shape create function, but not able to combine these.

```
Sub create_shape()

Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape

Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)

Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=24, Top:=65.6, Width:=672, Height:=26.6)

    Shp.Name = "My Header"
    Shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(184, 59, 29)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows you how to get each line or paragraph in a text box:

```
Sub LineByLine()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    ' for example only:
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
            MsgBox .Paragraphs(x).Text
        Next
        For x = 1 To .Lines.Count
            MsgBox .Lines(x).Text
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine. When no selection is made, it produce an error message **Selection ( unknown member) : Invalid request. This view doesn't support selection.** I tried add an if condition to check if a selection is made, can't find the proper method.

Comment: That was just a bit of example code to demonstrate how to split the text from a shape.  In your case, you'd replace "If .HasText Then MsgBox .TextRange.Text" with "If .HasText Then LineByLine(s)"  (and change LineByLine to accept a shape reference as a parameter ... LineByLine(oSh as Shape)  ... and make any internal changes to the sub to use oSh instead of the current selection.  Use your CreateShape code within LineByLine to create a shape with the text that it's current displaying in a msgbox

Comment: That worked. Inside HelloWorldMacro() , **If .HasText Then LineByLine(.TextRange) Exit Sub End If**. And accept the parameter as **LineByLine(oSh As TextRange)**. Inside LineByLine() call the **create_shape(.Lines(x).Text)**  to create shape with text.